# How to make corn nuts from fresh corn on the cob

Tags: roasting, corn

If I have some fresh, raw corn on the cob, how do I roast the corn kernels so that they can be used as croutons or eaten as a salty-snack? I don't want to make popcorn, but something that looks like these[image: roasted corn kernels]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You fry them in a saucepan with some oil (I use either olive or sunflower).

In order they don't explode an become pop-corn, you should have kept them in water for several (6~48) hours before frying them.

If you want them softer (and bigger), put them in water at 70°C for about 20~30 minutes.

How do you know they are done? When they are golden in the saucepan where you are frying them with oil. Take them out of the pan and add some salt.

Comment: I haven't tried but I guess letting them in the water is the part I was missing. Obvious now that I think about it! Anything specific as to what makes it more 6 hours or more 48 hours (it's a wide range) ?

Comment: The number of hours is more due to tradition than science. Typically you leave them in water "all through the night".

Comment: They are the second most common traditional snack in Spain (I'm sure it's eaten in many other countries too), after *pipas* (sunflower toasted seeds). In Spain *corn nuts* are known as [*kikos* or *quicos*](http://www.google.es/search?hl=es&q=receta+kikos).

Comment: If I wanted to make them in the oven, would that work too ?

Comment: I don't know. Never thought about it. In Spain, as well as *pipas* are toasted sunflower seeds, *kikos* are toasted corn. I guess it will be more similar to the industrial process, and probably will be able to control the temperature with more precision.